# PrimeFaces datatable overflow alignment issues

Tags: html, css, primefaces, jsf-2

I am using PrimeFaces and I need to accommodate many columns so I have used overflow: auto as style property but I have alignment issues with that.

Datatable image
[image]

Following is what I have tried:

```
<div style="width:100%; overflow:auto;">
    <p:dataTable var="msg" value="#{lazyMessageView.lazyModel}" 
                           paginator="true" rows="10"
                            paginatorTemplate="#{lbl['recordsPerPage']} {RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                            rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
                            selectionMode="single"
                            selection="#{lazyMessageView.selectedBean}"
                            id="messageTable" 
                            scrollable="true"  
                            scrollHeight="150" 
                            scrollWidth="100%"
                            resizableColumns="true"
                            draggableColumns="true"
                            rowKey="#{msg.creationTime}"
                            lazy="true"
```

Can anybody tell me how to manage columns lengths based on content they contain in PrimeFaces without losing their header? As so far header is behaving differently than that of table body.

Comment: does resizeable columns or cells with hints not a solution?

Comment: No, that also did not work , see all the variables used ( updated!).

Comment: Found the answer **min-width** was required to tell primefaces not to use less than that , so content is not trimmed.